# How to measure speed of a ball coming directly at you

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to measure the speed of a ball based on only radius as it travels towards an observer. Assuming we don't have any x and y data for the ball. The ball is thrown directly at you at eye level from 60 feet away. My first thought is to use visual radius growth rate to determine the speed (and more so when the ball will reach it's target). But I'm stuck on how to do this properly

In the real scenario, this will be done programmatically on video frames at regular intervals.

So let's assume the ball starts 60 feet (distance = 60) from the target. The ball has an absolute radius of 15. We can measure (and store/recall) exact visual radius at any interval along the way. We are not looking for a defined speed such as mph but rather growth rate of visual radius and time/intervals remaining til target reached.

Is there a formula to calculate the speed of the ball and/or intervals remaining until the ball reaches the target using only the information given?

Comment: I think you should look at the visual angle of the ball, rather than some sort of visual radius. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_angle).

Comment: A distinction must be made between the actual radius of the ball and its *apparent* radius to the observer. As the ball moves towards the observer its apparant radius will be increasing. I think you can set it up with a drawing showing the angle the ball makes with the eye of the observer, formed by a point at the eye and the two sides of the angle extending from the eye to the top and bottom of the ball at any instant.

Comment: Neglecting 3D vision, the eye usually doesn't see absolute distances, but angles. In this sense, you will need to track the growth rate of the angle. Having said that, you will also need the absolute (correct) radius of the ball, otherwise you cannot distinguish between a tennis ball or the moon approaching you (at very different speeds)

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments. I added some additional info to the question. Would it be incorrect to assume that visual radius would grow proportional to visual angle as the ball travels closer to the observer?

Comment: How is the visual radius not (effectively) infinite when the ball is at distance $0$?

Comment: Ted, fair point. Mathematically it would be infinite. In our case the camera is offset from the target point so it is visually approximately equal. That's my mistake for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

The apparent angular size will grow linearly as it approaches. The most convenient measure would be the angular diameter of the ball.

You can calculate that size with standard trig functions.  But you need to use the same units to measure the distance as to measure the ball. Angular size = sin(diameter / distance).  Distance = arcsin(apparent angular size) * diameter.

Also, at distance 0, the angular size will be 180 degrees and visual size would be infinite.

Added: Actually, if you know the starting distance and measure the angular size, that is all you need to know.  As it approaches, if the size is twice, it has come half the distance. If the size if 4 times, it has come 3/4 of the way.  (I should have said linearly as inverse of distance earlier).

Original size / Closer size = distance remaining / original distance

Comment: I’m slightly confused in that the angular size formula uses distance, and the distance formula uses angular size.

Comment: There are 3 variables.  Size of the ball, the distance, and the apparent size (as an angle).  The actual size of the ball isn't changing, so necessarily this will be true.

That is standard trig.  The diameter of the ball is the "opposite", the distance is the hypotenuse.  You use sin to get the angle from their ratios.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I'm reading it as: Angular size = sin(diameter / (arcsin(apparent angular size) * diameter))

If that's correct, then the part I'm missing is where apparent angular size comes from?

Comment: Angular size = sin(diameter / distance).  The next is just the same equation re-arranged to solve for distance.  Two equations.